# xRM - CRM Platform

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm

As Microsoft is trying to leverage xRM as a development Platform for LOB applications. Some of my clients start requesting applications to be developed on top of that platform.

I still need to know the right conditions where this platform will work and when the need arise to work in native .net environment so that i can convince my client.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether your LOB applications which will be developed on the top of Dynamics CRM 4.0 platform requiring a transaction support as the critical feature ?

Currently Dynamics CRM 4.0 web services doesn't support transaction, that means when you are executing a series of Dynamics CRM 4.0 web services call as a unit of work, you won't have a transaction support in the event of exception araised.

Comment: CRM2011 does support transactions on a plugin level, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking purely heuristically the following might influence a decision :

1. Is there an entity requirement to store client, account, address information and other related entities.
2. Is there a security requirement for users to 'own' data and specific functionality.
3. Is there an integration requirement for an API.
4. Is the a functional requirement for Workflow.
5. Is there a non-functional requirement for the clients to manage/maintain the system themselves.
6. Is there a low transactional throughput requirement (< 10 tps).

These questions often lead me to believe that an XRM solution is might be a good fit. An ideal example was a licensing solution and a government company register.